# Can I flatten multi depth self-referencing entities?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, flatten, self-reference

I have an entity self-references.

```
public class Category {

    private List<Category> children;
}
```

With given list of Categories, how can I flatten them all?

```
C11
    C21
        C31
        C32
    C22
C12
```

I want a list of

```
C1 C21 C31 C32 C22 C12
```

---

I tried.

```java
public static <T extends BaseEntity & SelfReferencing<T>> void flatten(
        final T parent, final Function<T, Stream<T>> function,
        final Consumer<T> consumer) {
    function.apply(parent).forEach(child -> {
        consumer.accept(child);
        flatten(child, function, consumer);
    });
}
```

Comment: @talex see my updates.

Comment: This function doesn't return anything it just iterates thru all elements.

Answer (score 2):

I took your code and improved it a little.

```
public static <T extends BaseEntity & SelfReferencing<T>> List<T> flatten(
        final T parent, final Function<T, Stream<T>> function) {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(parent);
    res.addAll(function.apply(parent).flatMap(child -> {
        flatten(child, function).stream();
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return result;
}
```

I don't see why you need `consumer` and I removed it. Also there are some conversion to stream and back.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a recursive function like the "flatten" one below?...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Flatten {

    static class Category {
        private List<Category> children;
        private String name;

        public Category(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Category> getChildren() {
            if(children == null) {
                children = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            return children;
        }

        public void setChildren(List<Category> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Category root = new Category("ROOT");
        Category c11 = new Category("C11");
        Category c12 = new Category("C12");
        Category c21 = new Category("C21");
        Category c22 = new Category("C22");
        Category c31 = new Category("C31");
        Category c32 = new Category("C32");

        root.getChildren().add(c11);
        root.getChildren().add(c12);
        c11.getChildren().add(c21);
        c11.getChildren().add(c22);
        c21.getChildren().add(c31);
        c21.getChildren().add(c32);

        List<Category> flat = flatten(root.getChildren());

        System.out.println(flat);
    }

    private static List<Category> flatten(List<Category> c) {
        List<Category> flatList = new ArrayList<>();

        flatten(flatList, c);

        return flatList;
    }

    private static void flatten(List<Category> flatList, List<Category> c) {
        for (Category category : c) {
            flatList.add(category);
            flatten(flatList, category.getChildren());
        }
    }
}
```

If there are "loops" in your hierarchy, (for example, C31 has C11 as a child), you can add the following to make sure things don't loop forever until you run out of memory...

```
private static void flatten(List<Category> flatList, List<Category> c) {
    for (Category category : c) {
        if(!flatList.contains(category)) {
            flatList.add(category);
            flatten(flatList, category.getChildren());
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you add...

```
c21.getChildren().add(c11);
```

To the "main" method, it should work without blowing up.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re heading for a Stream based solution, you can create the following method

```
public static <T> Stream<T> flatten(T node, Function<T,Stream<T>> children) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(node),
        children.apply(node).flatMap(ch->flatten(ch, children)));
}
```

and re-implement your “perform an action for each” method like

```
public static <T> void flatten(
    T parent, Function<T, Stream<T>> function, Consumer<T> consumer) {

    flatten(parent, function).forEach(consumer);
}
```

but since you said, you want a `List`, you can also use the streaming method like

```
public static <T> List<T> toFlatList(T parent, Function<T, Stream<T>> function) {
    return flatten(parent, function).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

being usable with your `Category` sketch like

```
List<Category> list=toFlatList(category, c -> c.getChildren().stream());
```